# Can't get members from group if distinguishedName has quotes

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I'm using `LdapContext` to query my `Active Directory`. It is impossible to get such `member` from `group`:

```
String userDn = "CN=Петров Иван Сидорович,OU=Отдел сбыта,OU=Здание \\\"Северное\\\",OU=Филиал Кааап-Рег,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com";
String searchFilter = "(&(ObjectClass=group)(member=" + userDn + "))";
```

However, if `members dn` has no quotes - everything is ok.

**ADDED LATER:**

I tryed query using VBScript like this:

```
Dim userDn
userDn = "CN=Петров Иван Сидорович,OU=Отдел сбыта,OU=Здание \""Северное\"",OU=Филиал Кааап-Рег,DC=sub,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

and query finished successfully!

(to add double quotes in vbs string you should add it twice)

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem of encoding missmatch ldap use utf8 cyrillic ad use cp1251 try to use reencoding like **new String(s.getBytes("CP1251"), "UTF8");**

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer to my question.

So, if your `distinguishedName` have `double quotes` or `plus` or other bad characters you should use.

```
package javax.naming.ldap;
Rdn.escapeValue(yourDn);
```

Actually we should use it always.

Answer (score -1):

That will not be an answer, but...

As soon you have an active directory, can you wipe out all cyrillic symbols out of your AD? If something fails, how will you dig into the restoring procedure?

And second. What the hell do you need quoting in your OU names? Did you ever read Microsoft recommendations?

And the answer seems to be - try to remove your quotations in OU names.

And - read carefully Microsoft's recommendations regarding AD infrastructure and OU's / CN's namings.